# How can my python script check whether there is a new version available on pypi repo?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, setup.py, pypi

I want to write a python script and make it available on a public pypi repository. Suppose I published version '1.0' and installed it.

Then, having version '1.0' installed, I publish version '1.1' to pypi repo.

When I run my script, I want it to print a warning if a new version exists remotely, no warning if it doesn't, and another warning if the check failed.

What's the best way of doing it?

EDIT: I am aware there are plenty of options for doing it, but when I ask "the best option" I mean whether a canonical interface I can rely on exist, and won't break if the pypi server or user environment changes. The less I depend on the environment, the better.

For instance, some drawbacks of some solutions:

1. Calling pip using subprocess - my code will break if pip is not in PATH
2. Using setuptools as a library - was setuptools meant to be used like that? What if they change the implementation of the library changing the method names? Should I depend on a specific version of setuptools?
3. Calling PYPI url directly - if these URLs change, it will break my code

I don't feel there is any good option to do it and I would love to be proven wrong.

Comment: I found many options of doing it, I just think I am not the only one with this problem and there must definitely be a way of being sure the user always have the latest version.

Possible solutions I've used:

1. Assume pip is installed and execute a pip command to check it
2. Use setuptools both as a dep lib and use it to check same thing pip does
3. Use requests lib and call an url directly in pypi repo

All those concern me because my code can break due to an external change. 
Any better option?

Comment: But you made actually a good point, let me update my question, maybe I wasn't clear enough...

Comment: If you have uploaded a version of a package, PyPI won't let you reupload it anyway, even if you removed it. I wouldn't check it at all.

Comment: not sure what you mean... I want to check whether there is a newer version remotely, not whether it was removed.